# How can I prevent people from sharing my Facebook photo?

Tags: facebook

I'd like to let people *view* my photos, but not share them with others.

Can I somehow prevent people from sharing my photos with others?

Comment: Please clarify: You want people to be able to see the things that you share, but not share them to others?

Comment: i want pople to ready only. not share

Comment: You can't prevent it. You can only make it a bit more inconvenient.

Answer (score 5):

There is no setting in Facebook to prevent reshare, so you cannot directly achieve this.

However you can ensure that only some people can see the post by not sharing anything with public visibility rather limit it to your friends. This way, even if other re-share it, only your friends can see it.

Alternatively you can choose Custom and only limit to specific friends of yours. For example if you have friends A, B, C, D. If you share a post only to and A, B, C by using Custom. If A decides to re-share it publicly, only B & C will be able to see it. D will not be able to see it because he doesn't have access to this originally.

[image]

However please keep in mind that if someone wants to share a picture that you don't want to be reshared, they can always do that in many ways. They can take a screenshot of the picture and re-upload if they want to do it by hook or crook. No privacy options can protect you.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that if I went back to the photo in question on my own page, changed the privacy setting to "Only Me" and then visited the other person's page where it had been shared previously that it had disappeared.  I then went back to my own page again and changed the setting on my photo back to "friends".  When I visited my friend's page one more time I found that my photo which she had shared earlier was still gone.  Guess she could choose to reshare it again if she was that determined. . .but for the time being, problem solved.  You could also message that person and ask them not to share it on their page citing your own personal privacy choices.

Comment: Your answer is not very clear.

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible, if you dont want people to share your photos, dont upload them anywhere on the internet. if you upload it anywhere, anyone can copy them and share them, whether via saving the file then reuploading it or taking a screenshot and then posting it elsewhere.